# Apache Lucene QueryParser.parse not using Analyzer on FuzzyQuery

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search, lucene, information-retrieval

With TermQuery and PhraseQuery my SerbianAnalyzer gets called but not with FuzzyQuery. I tried using lucene 4 and lucene 7 both with same behavior. 
I have following code:

```
Query query;
String field = "text";
String value = "дањ";

QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(field, new SerbianAnalyzer());

System.out.println("\nTermQuery");
query = new TermQuery(new Term(field, value));
System.out.println("Query (preParse): " + (TermQuery)query);
System.out.println("Query.toString(field1): " + ((TermQuery)query).toString(field));
System.out.println("Query (afterParse): " + queryParser.parse(((TermQuery)query).toString(field)));

System.out.println("\nPhraseQuery");
String[] terms = value.split(" ");
query = new PhraseQuery(field, terms);
System.out.println("Query (preParse): " + ((PhraseQuery)query));
System.out.println("Query.toString(field1): " + ((PhraseQuery)query).toString(field));
System.out.println("Query (afterParse): " + queryParser.parse(((PhraseQuery)query).toString(field)));

System.out.println("\nFuzzyQuery");
query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term(field, value), 1);
System.out.println("Query (preParse): " + ((FuzzyQuery)query));
System.out.println("Query.toString(field1): " + ((FuzzyQuery)query).toString(field));
System.out.println("Query (afterParse): " + queryParser.parse(((FuzzyQuery)query).toString(field)));
```

Result I'm getting is:

```
TermQuery Query (preParse): text:дањ  
Query.toString(field): дањ 
Query (afterParse): text:danj

PhraseQuery Query (preParse): text:"дањ"  
Query.toString(field): "дањ" 
Query (afterParse): text:danj

FuzzyQuery Query (preParse): text:дањ~1  
Query.toString(field): дањ~1 
Query (afterParse): text:дањ~1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that for a long time *QueryParser* wasn’t parsing queries properly (didn’t apply analyzers) if they were *FuzzyQuery*, *WildcardQuery*, *PrefixQuery*, *RegexpQuery*

To solve this problem, Lucene had [AnalyzingQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/analyzing/AnalyzingQueryParser.html) class, that overrides Lucene's default QueryParser so that Fuzzy-, Prefix-, Range-, and WildcardQuerys are also passed through the given analyzer, but wildcard characters * and ? don't get removed from the search terms.

However, starting from Lucene 7.4 this functionality was [merged](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7355?attachmentSortBy=fileName) into *QueryParserBase* which have now appropriate methods to handle those queries, like:

```
protected Query getFuzzyQuery(String field,
                              String termStr,
                              float minSimilarity)
```

So, instead of creating class `QueryParser`, you should create `ComplexPhraseQueryParser` that overriding this method and call parse from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works with AnalyzingQueryParser class in Lucene 4.0.
I tried to figure out how to get solution to work in Lucene 7.6 but with no result. QueryParser extends QueryParserBase but still does not parse FuzzyQuery. Should I make my own class that extends QueryParserBase in that case?